# How to round off a float values in django-python?

Tags: python, django, floating-point

if number is 0.1 then I want it to be 1.0 and same for all the numbers.
if a number has something in decimal place then I want to round it off to next digit.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil):

**python 2:**

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(0.1)
1.0
```

**python 3:**

```
>>> import math
>>> float(math.ceil(0.1))
1.0
```

Thanks to @PM 2Ring for pointing out the difference between python2 and python3.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `math.ceil()` returns an `int`, but in Python 2 it returns a `float`.

Comment: can you tell why it is returning float in python 2 and int in python 3?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9180047/3224008) speculates that it may have sth. to do with the introduction of long ints. But I really don't know if that's the real reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a lambda function that do the job.

```
>>> myround = lambda x: float(int(x)) if int(x) == x else float(int(x) + 1)
>>> myround(0.1)
1.0
>>> myround(2.0)
2.0
```

Comment: Although this code segment might answer the question, one should add an explanation to it.