# Why does print int (100*(11.20 - 11)) prints 19 instead of 20 in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, int

I have just started python tutorials.  Why does

```
print  int (100*(11.20 - 11))
```

print `19` instead of `20` in python ?? There is some sort of rounding off done by integer but i am unable to catch that. Help is appreciated.

Comment: not to mention that `print 100*(11.20 - 11)` echoes `20.0`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @dwn Actually, if you want to be technical about it, in that question the problem is that `+` is not exact, whereas in this question the problem is that `11.20` is not exactly `1120/100` and, if I'm not mistaken, all floating-point operations are exact.

Comment: The referenced question encompasses more than one operation, as do the answers

Comment: @dwn The accepted answer is the usual superstitious rubbish about `==` (equality operator which does not occur in this question) and doe snot explain why the floating-point result should be different from the expected one when **all the floating-point operations involved are exact**.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: The accepted answer is community wiki at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `11.20` is not exactly 1120/100 but slightly less than that. So `11.20 - 11` ends up slightly less than 20/100 (*). Multiplied by `100`, `11.20 - 11` produces a floating-point number slightly below 20, and since `int(...)` truncates (rounds towards zero), the result is 19.

For efficiency reasons, floating-point numbers are represented as fractions with a power of two as the denominator. So 1/2, 1/4, 1/16, … can be represented exactly as floating-point numbers, but 1/5 cannot (there is no power of two that can be used as the denominator to represent 1/5 exactly).

(*) This floating-point subtraction happens to be exact, so that the absolute error of the result compared to 20/100 is exactly the same as the absolute error of 11.20 compared to 1120/100. Note that the relative error is magnified, because the same absolute error is applied to a much smaller value. The subtraction of values that are already inexact and are close [is called “catastrophic cancellation”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance), and the subtraction in your Python line is one such catastrophic cancellation.

Answer (score 4):

```
11.2 - 11
```

actually yields

```
0.1999999999999993
```

which rounds down to 19.

Answer (score 1):

In Python [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) truncates toward 0 [for reasons Guido explains here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html). This means negative numbers will actually see the opposite effect ([related SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501279/how-do-i-only-round-a-number-float-down-in-python)).

Comment: “flooring” means rounding towards -infinity. `int(…)` truncates, which means rounding towards 0. They are the same thing for positive numbers but not for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As said, it is a rounding issue with floating points precision. You can see that using :

```
print '%.20f' % (100*(11.20 - 11))
>>> 19.99999999999992894573
```