# TypeError: a float is required,Python

Tags: python, list

I want to convert list of floats into integers.
My code

```
import math

data1 = [line.strip() for line in open("/home/milenko/Distr70_linux/Projects/Tutorial_Ex3/myex/base.txt", 'r')]
print type(data1)
data1c = [int(math.floor(i)) for i in data1]

print data1c[0]
```

What should I change?
File is huge,just couple of lines

```
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
1.200000e+03
```

Comment: You can cast strings to floats. `data1 = [float(line.strip()) for line in ...]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first cast to float:

```
[int(float(i)) for i in data1]
```

calling `int` will floor the number for you:

```
In [8]: int(float("1.23456e+03"))
Out[8]: 1234
```

You can do it all in the file logic:

```
with open("/home/milenko/Distr70_linux/Projects/Tutorial_Ex3/myex/base.txt", 'r') as f:
   floored = [int(float(line)) for line in f]
```

It is good practice to use  [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open your files, it will handle the closing of your files for you. Also *int* and *float* can handle leading or trailing white space so you don't need to worry about using strip.

Also if you were just wanting to pull the floats and not also floor, `map` is a nice way of creating a list of floats, ints etc.. from a  file or any iterable:

```
 floored = list(map(float, f))
```

Or using python3 where map returns an iterator, you could double map:

```
floored = list(map(int, map(float, f)))
```

The equivalent code in python2 would be using `itertools.imap`

```
from itertools import imap

floored = map(int, imap(float, f))
```

Answer (score 2):

Data read from files are always of `str` type where as parameter required for [`math.floor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582741/why-do-pythons-math-ceil-and-math-floor-operations-return-floats-instead-of) is a float

So you need convert it into float

```
data1c = [int(float(i)) for i in data1]
```